# Dereferencing data inside a struct ** inside a struct *

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is my struct code:

```
struct world {
   struct room** rooms;
   int num_rooms;
};

struct room {
   char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1];
   char* desc;
   char objects; // bit mask for OBJ_* flags
   struct room* exits[MAX_EXITS];
};
```

I'm trying to change the value of a room struct's objects in my world struct.

I've initialized a `struct world *world = worlds;`

What would the dereference code look like in order to change the values in one of the struct room *'s?

Comment: `struct * world = worlds` is not a valid statement.
Probably you mean something like this : http://ideone.com/rJyzpY
Just to show how the variable have to be used.

Comment: You haven't shown us how `rooms` is allocated. Presumably an array of pointers. And you haven't shown us what `worlds` is (points to a single struct or an array?). Anyway, it'll be something like: `world->rooms[index]->name`

Comment: As an off-topic observation, `char objects` should probably be of type `unsigned char` or, even better, `uint8_t`, if you're using it for bit flags.

Answer (score 1):

Assume `struct world * worlds = &someObject`, and if `worlds->rooms` is a pointer array to rooms, you could do as @Alan Au commented,

```
 struct room * r_array[] = {&room1, &room2, &room3};
 worlds->rooms = r_array;
 printf("%s\n", worlds->rooms[index]->name);
```

If `worlds->rooms`is a pointer to pointer of a single room , you can printf name like,

```
  printf("%s\n", (*worlds->rooms)->name);//or
  printf("%s\n", (*(*worlds).rooms)->name);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Preliminary fixup

I've 'fixed' (modified, at any rate) your initialization code from the syntactically incorrect:

```
struct *world = worlds
```

to the syntactically correct (but not necessarily what you had in mind):

```
struct world *world = worlds;
```

That would mean that somewhere else you also have the following declaration and code to initialize the pointer:

```
struct world *worlds;
```

Note that `struct world *world = worlds;` is legitimate because `struct world` is a type name (and the first `world` is a structure tag) and the second `world` is an identifier in the ordinary identifier namespace, not in the structure tags namespace.

#### Accessing rooms

Given:

```
int n = 1;  // For instance
```

You might write:

```
printf("Room %d: %s\n", n, world->rooms[n]->name);
```

That assumes you've initialized the structures properly.

Answer (score 1):

When `struct world *world` points to a valid `struct world`:

```
world->num_rooms = NUMBER_OF_ROOMS_IN_WORLD;
world->rooms = malloc(sizeof(*(world->rooms)) * world->num_rooms);
// FIXME: check error
for (unsigned int room_i = 0; room_i < world->num_rooms; ++room_i) {
    struct room *room = malloc(sizeof(*room)); // FIXME: check error
    world->rooms[room_i] = room;
    (void) strcpy(room->name, "room name");
    // ... etc, init the room
}
```

You can access an individual room's fields with `world->rooms[room_index]->field`, or, perhaps preferably, by first assigning to a pointer `struct room *room = world->rooms[room_index]` and then through `room->field`.